# android bug ? database stop generated suddenly in 17,111

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk

1. according to the DDMS the android just stop generate the sqlight file in  17,111 where outside of the DDMS if I import a file with the same values + the gap to my db it works just fine , is it my bug on the file who makes the db on the fly (onto the device in run time)?
2. how can i impot a  db file without using the DDMS(i add files manually how can i import one and insert db file to my sdk meanning complation time )?

Answer (score 0):

If you think you have found a bug, please create a new issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

In relation with your second question, I guess [this article](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) will give you some ideas.

Comment: No the bug was my wuth my sql before that i made a query that made dump and i didnt know why , it was a simple space missing :)